Brownian bridge - Calculation of the covariance
I know this question has already been answered here: Compute expectation and covariance of Brownian bridge  On the other hand, I follow a French book that doesn't take the same approach.
It's still a matter of calculating the covariance of the Brownian Bridge, with $\{X(t), 0  \le  t \le 1  \}$ and $s < t $ where $X(t) = B(t)-tB(1)$.
Now if we want $$ COV(X(t),X(s))$$ we find :
$$ COV(X(t),X(s)) = COV(B(t)-tB(1),B(s)-sB(1))$$ $$ = COV(B(t),B(s) - COV(B(t),sB(1)) -  COV(B(s),tB(1)) + COV(tB(1),sB(1))$$
Where $COV(B(t),B(s))= min\{s,t\} = s$ ,
and $COV(tB(1),sB(1))= st~COV(B(1),B(1)) = st$
Now my question is , I dont understand why  $COV(B(t),s~B(1))= s~COV(B(t),B(1)) = st$
( and same  for $t~COV(B(s),B(1)) = st$)
If we compute the definition of Covariance, we have :
$$ COV(B(t),B(1)) = E[B(t)B(1)] - E[B(t)]E[B(1)]$$ where the last part $= 0$. So I can't see why it is eqale to $t$ .
Thanks to you in advanced.

First note that $\mathbb{E}[B(t)]=0$ and therefore $\mathbb{E}[X(t)]=0$, which means that in any case the covariance is just the expectation of the product
$$\text{Cov}(B(t),sB(1))=\mathbb{E}[B(t)sB(1)].$$
Now we use that the expectation is linear, to take out the deterministic factor $s$
$$\mathbb{E}[B(t)sB(1)]=s\mathbb{E}[B(t)B(1)].$$
Finally, since we only consider $s,t\in[0,1]$, we have $t\le1$, thus
$$s\mathbb{E}[B(t)B(1)]=st.$$
In conclusion $\text{Cov}(B(t),sB(1))=st$. The other case is similar.

Thank you for your respond , but this is precisely that part , \mathbb{E}[B(t)B(1)]=t that I dont understand. Why is that ?

That is because $\mathbb{E}[B(t)B(1)]=\text{Cov}(B(t),B(1))=\text{min}(t,1)=t$.

Thank you a lot
